# Configuring SSO for Sharepoint 2010 with Azure AD

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, azure-ad, sso

I've been working through the tutorial from Microsoft on how to set up [Azure AD integration with Sharepoint on-prem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial). The article references SP 2016, but according to what I've been reading it should be the same for 2010 (I think?). I get as far as step 2 of the section on [configuring sharepoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial#configure-sharepoint-on-premises-single-sign-on), and successfully created a New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer. When I go to the Central Admin and to add the Trusted Identity Provider, it's not available as an option.

I've tried the basics, iisreset, recycle the app pool, etc. I even tried to do it with powershell (using  Set-SPWebApplication $applicationURL -AuthenticationProvider $issuer -Zone $zoneName, where $issuer is the one created above). The powershell attempt went poorly. I got a message about "Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll" being in use, and suddenly no default urls worked. That last took a bit to fix, so I'm a little gun-shy about experimenting.

Any pointers appreciated!